# Better ways to remove duplicate values of columns when using pl-sql "listagg" function in oracle

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, plsql, listagg

I have a table as you can see below :

```
c_id  |  Name1 |  Name2 |  Name3
--------------------------------
  1   |   a    |   b    |   c
  1   |   c    |   d    |   a
  2   |   d    |   e    |   a
  2   |   c    |   d    |   b
```

I want to write a query to have this output (Want to remove duplicates):

```
 c_id    Names
--------------------
  1      a,b,c,d
  2      a,b,c,d,e
```

I used `listagg` function and `unpivot` to do this :

```
select c_id, listagg(val, ',') within group(order by c_id) Names
  from (select distinct c_id, val
          from (select 1 c_id , 'a' name1, 'b' name2, 'c' name3
                  from dual
                union
                select 1 c_id , 'c' name1, 'd' name2, 'a' name3
                  from dual
                union
                select 2 c_id , 'd' name1, 'e' name2, 'a' name3
                  from dual
                union
                select 2 c_id , 'c' name1, 'd' name2, 'b' name3
                  from dual) v unpivot (val for namee in (name1, name2, name3)))
 group by c_id
```

I want to know If there are better ways to have the output mentioned above.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Since listagg(distinct...) is not supported I dont think you can simplify it much more. Imagining a table T instead of sample data and it looks pretty compact.